# C# obtengo una degradación en lugar de transparencia con picturebox

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net

Estoy intentando cubrir un form con un control picturebox, la idea es que este picturebox contenga una imagen de un color/tono violeta y que sea transparente permita ver otros controles debajo de el, similar a este ejemplo que encontré en internet:

Imagen con propósito ilustrativo: esta imagen tiene aplicado el efecto directamente al form yo busco hacerlo en un picturebox/imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he estado trabajando con la biblioteca de grafico en la siguiente clase:

```
namespace CreateImageClass
{
    public sealed class ImageControlOnFly
    {

        public Main MainForm;

        public Bitmap Bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);

        internal void StartTrackCoordinates()
        {
            CreateImageOverlay();
        }

        private void CreateImageOverlay()
        {

            getImage();
            SetImageOpacity((float)0.9);

            PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();
            picBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            picBox.Image = Bmp;
            picBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            picBox.Name = "pictAction";
            picBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            MainForm.Controls.Add(picBox);
            PictureBox picBoxControl = MainForm.Controls["pictAction"] as PictureBox;
            picBoxControl.BringToFront();

        }

        private void getImage()
        {
            using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp))
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Violet))
            {
                gfx.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, 1, 1);
            }
        }

        public void SetImageOpacity(float opacity)
        {
            try
            {

                //create a graphics object from the image  
                using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp))
                {

                    //create a color matrix object  
                    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();

                    //set the opacity  
                    matrix.Matrix33 = opacity;

                    //create image attributes  
                    ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();

                    //set the color(opacity) of the image
                    attributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);

                    //now draw the image  
                    gfx.DrawImage(Bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height), 0, 0, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

el problema es que el resultado es un degradado no se que esta mal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno me canse de buscar solución y no encontré y lo que encontré no me parecía funcionar para Windows 10.

como siempre tuve que buscar una solución alterna, en este caso fue colocar un form Secundarios con las mismas dimensiones sobre el form principal con la propiedad `Opacity = 0.30;`

Según algunas lecturas windows no permite aplicar transparencias a los elementos individuales si no que se debe aplicar al form ...

Comment: winforms.. en wpf no te pasa eso ;)

Comment: @gbianchi si, perooo en WPF el renderizado WebGL es pobre ya que todo lo "pinta" como si fuera un bitmap ... problemas de renderisado en CefSharp ... etc ... al final me daría mas problemas que soluciones ... tambien lo pase por las pruebas y no me convenció ...